# Why is object[key] not equal to key, if key is an object, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = new Object;
var b = new Object;
var c = new Object;

c[a] = a;
c[b] = b;

console.log(c[a] === a);
```

I tested the code above and get `false`. If I try `console.log(c[a] === b)`, then `true` is printed.

Why?

Comment: Why are you even doing this?

Comment: @VikashKesarwani - this is a good question. Most likely he's reduced the problem to an simple example.

Comment: Its not pointing like that which you had done in c++, Here is assignment problem. and there is no solution for this self disclosed form

Comment: You want to do `c.a = a` or `c['a'] = a`. That's for setting property names as if you were giving it a string. `c[a]` sets the property name to be the same as the value of `a`, a variable.

Comment: `console.log(c);` Mystery solved. Question is mundane.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem here has to do with how an `Object`'s keys are set. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Parameters):

> ### Parameters
>
> **nameValuePair1, nameValuePair2, ... nameValuePairN**
>
> - Pairs of names (strings) and values (any value) where the name is separated from the value by a colon.
>
> **value**
>
> - Any value.

An object's values can be accessed (via the appropriate key) in three ways:

```
var o = {};
var key = "fun";

// method 1:
o[key]    = "the key will be equal to `key.toString()"
// method 2:
o.key     = "the key will be equal to 'key'"
// method 3:
o["key2"] = "the key will be equal to `key2`"
/*
{
    "fun" : "the key will be...",    // method 1
    "key" : "the key will be...",    // method 2
    "key2": "the key will be..."     // method 3
}
*/
```

When using bracket notation, you need to mind the gap...between the brackets! Objects set their keys and values using the [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method, unless they're passed a string (then there's no point in `toString`). When using the dot notation, they use `.key` as the key.

Let's look at your case:

```
var a = {}
  , b = {}
  , c = {}
  ;

c[a] = a;
// `a` is not a string, and we're using brackets, so the key
// will be equal to `key.toString()`:
// a.toString() === "[object Object]"
// Try the following in your console: `{}.toString()`
// Note how this is different from console.log({}), since
// the console exposes your object (that's why the dev console is useful)
// c is now: `{ "[object Object]" : a }`

c[b] = b;
// b is also an object, so `b.toString()` is the same as `a.toString()`
// that means c is now `{ "[object Object]" : b }`

assert c[a] === a
// a.toString() == b.toString() == "[object Object]"
// and we just noted that c was `{ "[object Object]" : b }`
// so of course this is false
assert c[b] === b
// true because c[b] == b;
assert c["[object Object]"] === b;
// also true
assert c.b === b
// false, since `c` has no "b" key (c.b is `undefined`)
```

Comment: exactly, as i mention note for self disclosed assignment in above comment

Comment: Isn't `a.toString()` the string `"[object Object]"`?

Comment: @slebetman you're right; I was thinking of JSON. I will fix that (although it's the same concept)

Comment: I think `a.toString` would return the function object, but `a.toString()` will call the function.

Comment: What would happen if `var c = new Array`? Just out of curiosity. Would it work as the OP expects?

Comment: @2pha you'd be doing `c['[object Object]'] = {}`, which would leave the `c` array unchanged, since you're accessing it through a string, and not an index.

Comment: After playing for a while I think I understand. It is because the second assignment is overriding the first. Because `c[a]=a` and `c[b]=b` are the same as `c["[object Object]"] = a` and `c["[object Object]"] = b`

Comment: @2pha I rewrote my answer and tried to make it more concise. What you wrote is exactly what happens.

Comment: @royhowie  The most useful answer to this question I've ever seen today.You really help me a lot! ps:your photo looks handsome too.

Comment: A fun little corner-case that's also the side effect of this is that `c[1]` is the same as `c["1"]`. Try it.

Comment: The explanation is a bit wrong. The reason is not because how property keys are set. It's due to how the square bracket operator works. Everything inside a square bracket after an object is assumed to be a string and if it's not the `.toString` method of the thing will be called. So `1` will be converted to `"1"` and `{}` will be converted to `"[object Object]"`. The correct documentation is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 8):

Object is not a valid key for JavaScript Object, only strings are

So, when you do this:

```
c[a] = a;
c[b] = b;
```

The compiler can not use the a or b as a key for c as in c[a] or c[b].

However, it does not fail, because JavaScript can work around this problem. First it figures out that

1. The variable is an object and
2. The variable has toString -function

Thus, the JavaScript compiler will call toString() of each of those variables. And by default, the Object.prototype.toString it will return "[object Object]" -string, because the implementation is the default implementation which does that and that value becomes the new key

```
c["[object Object]"] = a;
c["[object Object]"] = b; // overrides the previous
```

Which is not what you wanted. The problem is that toString will by default return always the same value, so assigments will always go to the same key.

To demonstrate that toString is actually the problem, you can actually do a **horrible cheat** to make each object return unique string

```
// don't do this!!! 
(function() {
  var id=1;
  Object.prototype.toString = function() {
   if(!this._id) this._id = id++;
   return "Object"+this._id;
  }
}());
```

After that key of c[a] will be c["Object1"] and c[b] will be c["Object2"] and so on... and the c[a] == a and  c[b] == b are working as expected, but in real life this is not a good solution.

An acceptable way to solve this would be either use some other key, perhaps an ID assigned to the object like c[a.id] = a or to use ES6 Map Object, where any value, including Objects, can be used as a key.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

> The Map object is a simple key/value map. Any value (both objects and
>   primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value.

Comment: Thanks.It's much more clearer of this question now,but i'm still confused about how to use c[a.id] as you recommend

Comment: It depends a bit of what you intent to do, but If you want to find objects from the "hash" c, you could assign to each object some unique ID, like obj.id = 1234; and then assing the value to c like c[obj.id] = obj; and then if you want to look for the objects from the hash, search using c[<id>] or c[someObject.id] etc.

Answer (score -3):

I experimented with it a lit bit and @royhowie might be right. As you can see in this implementation I switched the order of the assignments and then c[a] == a gave a true.

```
var a = new Object;
var b = new Object;
var c = new Object;

//I switched the following lines of code
c[b]=b; 
c[a]=a;

console.log(c[a]===a);
```

Output: true

Comment: Yeah,your switch makes it entirely different situation.